# Error while using std::map

Tags: c++, boost, stdmap

In the following code, I'm trying to understand how map lookup works with user-defined data as key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp>

#include "unicode/coll.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace icu;

class mystring {
public:
    std::string s;
    bool operator==(const mystring &s1) const;
    bool operator!=(const mystring &s) const;
    bool operator<(const mystring &s1) const;
    bool operator>(const mystring &s1) const;
    bool operator<=(const mystring &s1) const;
    bool operator>=(const mystring &s1) const;
};

int caseCompare(UnicodeString& str1, int32_t len1, UnicodeString& str2, int32_t len2)
{
    int ret;
    ret = str1.caseCompare(0, len1, str2, 0, len2, 0);
    cout << "caseCompare: " << ret << endl;
    return ret;
}

bool mystring::operator==(const mystring &s1) const
{
    cout << "== operator" << "\n";
    cout << s << "\t" << s1.s << "\n";
    UnicodeString us1(s.c_str(), s.length());
    UnicodeString us2(s1.s.c_str(), s1.s.length());

    if(caseCompare(us1, s.length(), us2, s1.s.length() != 0)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

bool mystring::operator<(const mystring &s1) const
{
    UnicodeString us1(s.c_str(), s.length());
    UnicodeString us2(s1.s.c_str(), s1.s.length());

    int ret;

    cout << "< operator" << "\n";
    cout << s << "\t" << s1.s << "\n";

    size_t smaller_size;
    if (s.size() < s1.s.size()) {
        smaller_size = s.size();
    } else {
        smaller_size = s1.s.size();
    }

    ret = caseCompare(us1, s.length(), us2, s1.s.length() != 0);
    if(ret != 0) {
        if (ret < 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if ((s.size() == s1.s.size()) || (s.size() > s1.s.size())) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

bool mystring::operator!=(const mystring &s1) const
{
    cout << "!= operator" << "\n";
    cout << s << "\t" << s1.s << "\n";

    if (!(*this == s1)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

bool mystring::operator>(const mystring &s1) const
{
    cout << "> operator" << "\n";
    cout << s << "\t" << s1.s << "\n";

    if ((!(*this < s1)) && (!(*this == s1))) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

bool mystring::operator<=(const mystring &s1) const
{
    cout << "<= operator" << "\n";
    cout << s << "\t" << s1.s << "\n";

    if ((*this < s1) || (*this == s1)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

bool mystring::operator>=(const mystring &s1) const
{
    cout << ">= operator" << "\n";
    cout << s << "\t" << s1.s << "\n";

    if ((*this > s1) || (*this == s1)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

typedef boost::tuple<class mystring, class mystring> Key;
int data = 100;

typedef std::map<Key, int, std::less<Key> > Testmap;
Testmap map1;

int main(void)
{
    mystring str1;
    mystring str2;

    string str3, str4;

    cout << "String1: " << endl;
    cin >> str3;
    cout << "String2: " << endl;
    cin >> str4;

    str1.s = str3;
    str2.s = str4;

    Key fk = boost::make_tuple(str1, str2);
    map1.insert(std::make_pair(fk, data));

    cout << "String1: " << endl;
    cin >> str3;
    cout << "String2: " << endl;
    cin >> str4;

    str1.s = str3;
    str2.s = str4;

    fk = boost::make_tuple(str1, str2);

    Testmap::iterator itr = map1.find(fk);
    if (itr != map1.end()) {
        cout << itr->second << "\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Not found";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When this code is compiled, I get this error:

```
$ g++ map_test.cc -licuuc -licui18n
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/string:50,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/ios:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/iostream:40,
                 from map_test.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_tree.h:1170:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, _Val = std::pair<const boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, int> >, _Compare = std::less<boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, int> >]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_map.h:500:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>&) [with _Key = boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::tuples::tuple<mystring, mystring, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, int> >]’
map_test.cc:146:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_function.h:230: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
```

I suppose it is unable to find the `<` operator, but this is defined in `class mystring`. Or is it complaining of a lack of allocator method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include `boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp`

Make the comparison operator as per your requirement, I have just shown it as an example.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#using_library

Comment: @jv_ oops..updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: Your comparison operator doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @Arunmu: Including the header solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @juanchopanza I know, that was just for the sake of defining one. I have mentioned that at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: `std::map` has specific requirements for the key comparison. I don't think your satisfies those.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am not aware of any such specific requirement for `map`. For `set`, I know it must be strict weak ordering. Can you point to some resource which talks about it ?

Comment: Look it up. The information is everywhere. There are a zillion SO questions about it.

Comment: ` The key comparison function, a Strict Weak Ordering whose argument type is key_type; it returns true if its first argument is less than its second argument, and false otherwise. This is also defined as map::key_compare.` My operator seems to be fine w.r.t this, atleast from what I wanted.

Comment: `{1,2}<{2,1}=>true`, `{2,1}<{1,2}=>true`.

Comment: @jv_ Understood. Thanks!